# I killed all the orcs, and now villas is being stupid and following me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to all the strongholds, and killed all the orcs, yet apparently I still have a 4000 gold bounty. Normally in the past, when villas were being really annoying, I would just pay off all my bounties and he stops, but I can't get rid of the orc bounty because I killed them all.

How do I get rid of my orc bounty? I am playing on Xbox 360.

Comment: Do you mean Vilkas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are attacked by a guard, draw your weapon and sheath it again. This will be seen as a surrender by the guard and it will talk normally to you. Then you can pay the bounty just as usual.